# How to suppress "file written" shortmess?

Tags: vimrc

Upon saving a file, vim shows a message like,

```
"file" [New] 0L, 0C written
```

I want to suppress this message. I have tried adding `shortmess+=FW` to my `~/.vimrc` but it doesn't seem to work.